# How can I make a code that tells VB6 that tells VB6 that you're inputting something other than Whole numbers?

Tags: forms, vb6

**Introduction:** Hi, everyone! I'm new to VB6! How can I make a code that tells VB6 that tells VB6 that you're inputting something other than Whole numbers?

**Details:** I'm making an arithmetic progression calculator (I think the code is not needed? but I'll just provide just in case.) Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btCalc_Click()
    Dim A As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim D As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim F As Long
    
    A = Val(txtInitterm.Text)
    N = Val(txtTermint.Text)
    D = Val(txtFinterm.Text)
    R = Val(txtTermint.Text)
    
    F = N / 2 * (2 * A + (N - 1) * D)
    
    lblOutput.Caption = F
    
End Sub
```

and I wanna notify or tell VB6 that I'm putting in a fraction, not an integer and uses that fraction to do operations.

**NOTE:** String Fraction to Value in VBA this doesn't answer my question... :D

**Thank you for helping me, everyone! it's much appreciated.**

Comment: I don't think there's a way to _tell_ VB6 a TextBox contains a fraction but you could _assume_ this is the case and respond accordingly.

Comment: `Long` is an integer type.  You probably want to use `Single` or `Double` instead of `Long`.

Comment: Is there any reason you're learning VB6? It's incredibly outdated now, with the last release over 20 years ago. Much better to learn VB.Net if that's an option? (Or better yet C#)

Comment: @Slugsie I'm always curious about that too! VB6 does still have a huge codebase that is being maintained however, so that could be one reason.

Comment: I just feel like I want to code in VB6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Application.Evaluate(...)` in Vb6 like in VBA, so you have to do it like the "question" in "String Fraction to Value in VBA".  Extract the logic to a function for re-use, and replace the `Val(...)` calls with the function for use.

Something like below would likely work, although you may want to provide better error handling in the obvious bad-math cases.  I simply return zero and mark them with a comment.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btCalc_Click()
    Dim A As Long, N As Long, D As Long, R As Long, F As Long
    
    A = GetFrac(txtInitterm)
    N = GetFrac(txtTermint)
    D = GetFrac(txtFinterm)
    R = GetFrac(txtTermint)
    
    F = N / 2 * (2 * A + (N - 1) * D)
    
    lblOutput.Caption = F
    
End Sub


Public Function GetFrac(ByVal S As String) As Double
  GetFrac = 0         ' default return on error
  If InStr(S, "/") = 0 Then GetFrac = Val(S): Exit Function
  Dim P() As String, N As Double, D As Double
  P = Split(S, "/")
  If UBound(P) <> 1 Then Exit Function  ' bad input -- multiple /'s
  N = Val(P(0))
  D = Val(P(1))
  If D = 0 Then Exit Function ' div by 0
  GetFrac = N / D
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and it answers my question thank you! :D